# Changing ntpversion in ntpq packets

Tags: ntp, kali-linux

So im using ntpq Ver 4.2.8p13, and it seems the default NTP Version that it claims in packages is version 2, as shown by:

```
root@kali:~# ntpq -c ntpversion
NTP version being claimed is 2
```

However, when i try changing this, I go into interactive mode

```
root@kali:~# ntpq
ntpq> ntpversion 
NTP version being claimed is 2
ntpq> ntpversion 4
ntpq> ntpversion
NTP version being claimed is 4
ntpq> exit
root@kali:~# ntpq -c ntpversion
NTP version being claimed is 2
```

So as soon as i exit interactive mode, the claimed version is being restored to default, how can I make persistant changes to this value?

Answer (score 0):

I tested this on another server running the same version, and it also reports version 2 when running that command. It clearly does run and support version 4 (as does everything else since version 4 has been the standard since 2001).

After a lot of googling, it seems that the ntpq program itself uses version 2 for some odd reason by default, and the NTP server tries to be helpful and accommodating, and will dutifully reply in version 2 as well, causing ntpq to think that the server is running version 2. You can see this behaviour in your testing, as when you in interactive mode set the version to 4 for the ntpq program, the claimed version jumps up to 4.

The take-home here is that ntpq is ancient and behaves in mysterious ways, and that your server most definitely supports version 4.